# Ogmios Node Stopped Working

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-graphql

I did follow cardano-graphql guide and I was running my node smoothly for 2 months today It gave me this error and couldn't understand what is wrong with it. I restarted the container but didn't solve my problem.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                                    NAMES
59bdf858b940        inputoutput/cardano-graphql-hasura:6.2.0              "docker-entrypoint..."   2 months ago        Up 2 months                  0.0.0.0:8090->8080/tcp                                   cardano-graphql-hasura-1
2c4608f0384f        postgres:11.5-alpine                                  "docker-entrypoint..."   2 months ago        Up 2 months                  0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                   cardano-graphql-postgres-1
2d17673d47ba        inputoutput/cardano-db-sync:12.0.0                    "/nix/store/5ghw8r..."   2 months ago        Up 2 months                                                                           cardano-graphql-cardano-db-sync-extended-1
2f8ed0c5755a        inputoutput/cardano-graphql:6.2.0-mainnet             "node index.js"          2 months ago        Up 8 weeks                   0.0.0.0:3100->3100/tcp                                   cardano-graphql-cardano-graphql-1
d26dcadce926        cardanosolutions/cardano-node-ogmios:v5.1.0-mainnet   "/root/cardano-nod..."   2 months ago        Up About an hour (healthy)   3000/tcp, 12788/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1337->1337/tcp, 12798/tcp   cardano-graphql-cardano-node-ogmios-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Cardano went through Hard Fork event (Vasil fork) while the old node/dbsync/ogmios versions - you'd need to upgrade your components